# How do I prove: $\cos (\theta + 90^\circ) \equiv - \sin \theta $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I go about proving this?
I know one method is:

$\eqalign{
   \cos (90^\circ + \theta ) &\equiv \cos90^\circ \cos\theta  - \sin90^\circ \sin\theta   \cr 
  &  \equiv (0)(\cos\theta ) - (1)(\sin \theta )  \cr 
  &  \equiv  - \sin \theta  \cr} $

I'd appreciate others, particularly ones that will allow me to visualize this identity on the unit circle.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Most of the answers to your [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336003/) generalize straightforwardly to this case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Could you explain how please, this is confusing me i cant get my head around it, thank you!

Comment: `<pedant>`$\cos 90 \neq 0$, but $\cos \frac\pi2 = \cos90^\circ = 0$`</pedant>`

Comment: Ah I missed the degrees symbol? I'll be careful next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd appreciate others, particularly ones that will allow me to visualize this identity on the unit circle.

The picture represents the trigonometric unit circle. The angle $\theta=\angle AOP$ is represented in the first quadrant, but it is a generic orientate angle. $|AP|=\sin\theta$. $\angle AOQ=\theta+90^\circ$. The right triangle $[O,A,P]$ is similar to the right triangle $[O,B,Q]$, because $\angle BQO=\angle AOP=\theta$. Since $|OP|=|OQ|=1$, both triangles are congruent and $$\cos(\theta+90^\circ)=-|OB|=-|AP|=-\sin\theta.$$

[image]

Comment: @Assad: You are welcome!

Comment: how OB=Cos(90°+θ)?

Comment: @user3788135 $\cos (\theta +90^{\circ})<0 $ and $\cos (\theta+90^{\circ})=-|OB|/|OQ|=-|OB|/1=-|OB|$.

Comment: I think OB has to be cos (90° - θ).

Comment: how cos (90° + θ) = Cos (90°- θ) of triangle BOQ?

Comment: $\cos(\theta + 90^{\circ})= \sin(90^{\circ}-(90^{\circ}+\theta) =sin(- \theta) =-sin(\theta) = - \cos(90^{\circ}-\theta)$

Comment: In the Figure OB= $ \cos(90^{\circ}+\theta)$ I think it should be $ -\cos(90^{\circ}+\theta)$

Answer (score 3):

The point $P$ on the unit circle corresponding to $\theta$ is $\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$. Assume for a moment that $P$ is not on either coordinate axis; then it’s on the line $y=(\tan\theta)x=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}x$.

The point $Q$ corresponding to $\theta+\frac{\pi}2$ is on the perpendicular line through the origin, whose slope is $-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$. But $Q$ is also the point $\left\langle\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right),\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)\right\rangle$, so

$$\frac{\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)}{\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)}=-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\;.\tag{1}$$

The two sides of $(1)$ are evidently the two square roots of $\cot^2\theta$, and they have the additional property that the squares of numerator and denominator sum to $1$, so they must be identical except for sign. Thus, either

$$\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)=\sin\theta\quad\text{and}\quad\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)=-\cos\theta\;,$$

or

$$\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)=-\sin\theta\quad\text{and}\quad\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)=\cos\theta\;,$$

and consideration of quadrants rules out the former. The case in which $P$ is on a coordinate axis is easily handled separately.

Comment: The point Q is in the second quadrant of the unit circle as the angle $\theta  + {\pi  \over 2}$ is obtuse (if im not mistaken?), shouldnt the corresponding cosine coordinate be negative? i.e. $ - cos(\theta  + {\pi  \over 2})$?

Comment: @Assad: $Q$ can be in any quadrant; it depends on $\theta$, which need not be in the first quadrant. If $\theta$ is in the first quadrant, $\sin\theta>0$, so $\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)=-\sin\theta<0$, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 I strongly favor students learning trig functions in terms of the unit circle.

Comment: @Calvin: For a very first exposure the triangle does have the advantage of familiarity, but I certainly wish that there were a much greater emphasis on the unit circle approach early on. Sadly, of the three (triangle, circle, analytic) it was the one with which most of my students were **least** comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that sine and cosine are **co**-functions, meaning that they are connected through complementary angles (this is evident for $\newcommand{\dg}{^\circ} 0\dg \le \theta \le 90\dg$ from geometry of a right triangle).
$$\begin{align}
\cos \theta &= \sin(90\dg - \theta)\\
\sin \theta &= \cos(90\dg - \theta)
\end{align}
$$

Now, sine is an odd function, which means that
$$\sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta \qquad \text{for all } \theta.$$

Putting these together:

$$
\cos(\theta + 90\dg) = \cos(90\dg - (-\theta)) = \sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) we get:
$$\cos(90 + \theta) = \cos (\pi/2 + \theta) = \frac{e^{i(\pi/2 + \theta)}+e^{-i(\pi/2 + \theta)}}{2} = \frac{e^{i\theta}  e^{i\pi/2}+e^{-i\theta} e^{-i\pi/2}}{2} = \frac{ie^{i\theta}  - ie^{-i\theta}}{2} = -\frac{e^{i\theta}  - e^{-i\theta}}{2i} = -\sin(\theta) $$

Comment: This is probably not elementary enough for someone taking precalculus and trigonometry for the first time :-)

Answer (score 1):

$\sin$ is the vertical position. $\cos$ is the horizontal position. If you add 90 to the angle $\theta$, that's equivalent to rotating the coordinate system by 90°: the axes switch places.

Answer (score 0):

So you have cos(x+90)=-sin(x)
You know that cos(90-x)=sin(x), and hopefully this make sense why (if not, imagine a right triangle with angles x and 90-x. Take the sin x and cos(90-x) and you will see they will be the same). You also know that cos (w)=cos(-w) (you can see why this is by imagining w and -w on the unit circle). So let's factor a -1 from cos(90-x). We are left with cos(x-90)=-sin(x). Now remember that cos(x)=-cos(x+180). So let's apply this to our problem. 
-cos(x-90+180)=sin(x), so cos(x+90)=-sin(x)