# How is $\cos (\pi/2+h)$ equal to $-\sin(h)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am not able to grasp the logic behind how $\cos(\frac \pi2+h) = -\sin(h)$.
I was able to find an explanation on Reddit but it is not clear. Can anybody elaborate in a better way?

Here is the link to the explanation - [reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/2g91n9/ap_calculuslimit_as_h_approaches_0_of_cospi2_h_h/)

Comment: What definitions of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are you using?

Comment: What is $\cos(A+B)$

Comment: The question i am referring to is available at https://www.targetpublications.org/download/hsc-maharashtra-board/maharashtra-hsc-mathematics-paper-2.pdf. It is problem no xiii) and solution is given as well. Its just that the solution mentions cos(π/2+h) equal to -sinh without any explanation or citation like trig. identity. Hence needed elaboration on this.

Comment: The question on reddit is about computing a limit.  Here you are just asking about a trigonometric identity.  I am confused about what it is that you actually want to know.  It would also be helpful if you could provide more context.  What theorem and definitions can you work with?  How are you defining the trigonometric functions (in terms of triangles? circles? power series? differential equations?)?  Do you know any complex analysis (one of the answer provided below uses it)?  Do you know any angle addition formulae (another answer uses that)?

Comment: Yes it a limits and continuity chapter with trig. identities used in solution to simplify and arrive at a conclusion. Its just I wanted to see pattern of same kind. This solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349495/how-do-i-prove-cos-theta-90-circ-equiv-sin-theta was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** One way to define $\cos x$ is $$\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$ and, similarly, one can write $\sin x$ as $$\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i},$$ where $i$ is defined such that $i^2=-1$. Use $e^{i\pi}=-1$.